# How to map right shift to slash using xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping

How to map <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> to slash (<kbd>/</kbd>) using `xmodmap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = slash question slash question" #this will make Shift_R to act as slash
```

To get this change for every session, after you have run the ​​previous command, create a file called `.xmodmap` with the new keymaps, using the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

Comment: I just restared my system (ubuntu 13.04) and the `.xinitrc` part didn't work. By now I'm going to ad `xmodmap .xmodmap` to session applications list. If you know the issue please updade. Thanks.

Comment: @chico Try to `chmod 755 ~/.xinitrc` and see if the problem persists.